# why my web security configuration does not execute?

Tags: spring, oauth

I am trying to implement Google authentication using Spring Boot. However, for some reason, my WebSecurityConfig class is not being executed even though I am using the correct annotations and my package is located under MyPlayersApplication  so the component scan should be able to read it. What am I missing here?

```
package com.api.gateway.myplayers.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import static com.api.gateway.myplayers.security.AuthUtils.*;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Value("${GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}")
    private String googleClientId;
    @Value("${GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET}")
    private String googleClientSecret;

    @Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(googleClientRegistration());
    }

    private ClientRegistration googleClientRegistration() {
        return ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId(CLIENT_NAME)
                .clientId(googleClientId)
                .clientSecret(googleClientSecret)
                .userInfoUri(USER_INFO_URI)
                .clientName(CLIENT_NAME)
                .redirectUri(REDIRECT_URI)
                .scope(SCOPE.EMAIL.getValue(), SCOPE.PROFILE.getValue(), SCOPE.OPENID.getValue())
                .authorizationUri(AUTHORIZATION_URI)
                .tokenUri(TOKEN_URI)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequest ->
                        authorizeRequest
                                .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                                .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login()
                .loginPage("/auth/login")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
        return http.build();

    }
}
```

MyPlayerApplication:

```
 package com.api.gateway.myplayers;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class MyPlayersApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```